# jQuery UI position() options do not affect result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I am working on a form validation script, and got stuck on a problem with jQuery UI `position()` function. No matter what options I would set, the result is still the same...

For example:

```
$(...).position({
        'of': $(obj),
        'my': 'bottom left', <--- left
        'at': 'top center'
})
```

and

```
$(...).position({
        'of': $(obj),
        'my': 'bottom right', <--- right
        'at': 'top center'
})
```

... position of object in totally the same place.

[Test Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/j8g2F/1/)

At first I thought that jQuery maight not read the object `width()` properly, but as you can see in attached fiddle, `msg_box` has `width()`.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to position error message on top of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was trivial. It should be `my': 'right bottom'` not `my': 'bottom right'`. First `horizontal`, second `vertical`.